# How to sort text from XML file as number in WPF DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, sorting, datagrid

The content of my DataGrid (Product and Price, for example) is loaded from an XML file and every thing is treated as text when sorted by the DataGrid.

How to tell the DataGrid to treat Price as number when sorting? Thanks.

Here's the relevant XAML (there's NO code behind). I want to sort Length as number:

```
 <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length" SortMemberPath="Length" Width="100">
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding XPath=Length}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Showing your code is always better than just words.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add a Converter to your Binding.
Step 1 : Create the converter class.

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(int))]
public class StringToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Int32.Parse(value.ToString());
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

A little validation might be advisable, but this is only a rudimentary example.

Step 2: instantiate the converter. Make sure you add the Namespace declaration to your Xaml.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StringToIntConverter x:Name="stringToInt"/>   
</Window.Resources>
```

Step3 : use it

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Length" SortMemberPath="Length" Width="100">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock TextAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"  Text="{Binding XPath=Length, Converter={StaticResource stringToInt}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1):

Without code, this is just a guess, but I'm assuming you are doing a xml deserialization into an object, that is put in a list and then your datagrid is bound to the list.  If you make the price data field in the list class an int, then datagrid will treat it as a number.

Comment: No, there is no kind of serialization done in code behind. Everything is just declarative in the XAML file as added to question.